# Prove that the equation $x^2=x$ has the same solutions in rational numbers as in integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

I was wondering if you could help me start in my discrete math homework. I'm asked to prove that A = B:

$A =\{x \in \mathbb{Z}\mid x^2 = x\}$ and $B = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}\mid  x^2 = x\}$

I'm having problems as to where to start and I wanted to know where to begin this problem.

Comment: First compute the elements of each set and it'll be obvious

Comment: What numbers do you know such that $x^2=x$?

Comment: Surely you know the solutions.

Comment: 0 and 1 are numbers that $x^2 =  x$

Comment: So all that's left is to figure out of those numbers are integers and/or rational.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: rewrite it in the form $$x(x-1)=0$$

Comment: And also rely on the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain and $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.